# Using C# Can I tell if an application is pre-installed on a Windows 8.1 box

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-8.1

So, I can use the registry to find what applications are installed on a **windows 8.1** system, however, is it possible to tell if these are pre-installed with the system or have been installed by the user?

I know I can do this using Win RT for store apps, but **can I do it for windows without using RT?**

Comment: yes you can do that...

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Awesome! ummmmm... how? :-)

Comment: Write a solid specification of what distinguishes a user install from a system pre-install, and you're done. Reading the registry to find what applications are installed? Well, no, that's not how its done. You should look into the [Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688.aspx) services instead (see [Using Windows Installer to Inventory Products and Patches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369558.aspx)).